# DataGridView population with variable WHERE clause (MySQL/Net Connector)

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, xsd, where-clause

I am using the MySQL/Net Connector for my VS 2010 VB.NET application. I managed to automatically fill my DataGridView using the little operation arrow up over the DataGridView and it received data well.

Now the results are displaying properly; however, the results are divided into lists and the list should be selectable from a ComboBox - creating a where clause that filters the result only for results from the correct list.

It would be something like: WHERE list = ComboBox.Text.ToString

However the query is only within the xsd file and I don't see how I can get the value from my ComboBox into that query.

Is there a way to get the query into my Form.vb or anywhere where the ComboBox value is available? I feel like this should be possible...

And ideas? If you don't get me yet: Ask me. I might be hard to understand.

Comment: Didn't you ask this same question just 9 hours prior to posting this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16491732/where-clause-in-database-populated-datagridview-vb-net

Comment: I thought it was a little hard to understand. I'm new on here.

Comment: Okay, but for your future reference you can edit your questions.  You don't need to start a new one to clarify yourself.